# Erro 404 na segunda rota usando Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, route, http-status-404

Bom dia.

Configurei meu app no Cpanel que usa passenger_wsgi.py (não sei se essa informação é relevante)

Versão do Python 3.7.3 e a Versão do Flask==1.1.1

A rota principal funciona bem, mas a segunda quando tento acessar dá erro 404.

Alguém já passou por esse problema antes?

Segue o código: (url: http://funtraveldetective.com/ftd)

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
application = app # our hosting requires application in passenger_wsgi

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Index Page'

@app.route('/teacher/')
def hello_teacher():
    return 'Hey Teacher'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta tirar a barra do final e deixar somente '/teacher'

assim:

```py
@app.route('/teacher')
def hello_teacher():
    return 'Hey Teacher'
```